# Display all messageHeader's values

Tags: c#, wcf

I'd like to know what is the best way to display all MessageHeaders server side. Actually the only way I know is the following:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<T>(Name, Namespace)
```

That method is only for a known MessageHeader but I'd like to display their values in a loop.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The headers are loopable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Count; ++i)
{
    MessageHeaderInfo h = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders[i];
    // for any reference parameters with the correct name & namespace
    if (h.IsReferenceParameter && 
        h.Name == IDName && 
        h.Namespace == IDNamespace) 
    {
        // read the value of that header
        XmlReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i);
        id = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
}
```

Found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395213.aspx)