# WCF: there is not a header with name '' and namespace '' in the message

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

ERROR: there is not a header with name ' ' and namespace ' ' in the message

I have a WCF service that needs to retrieve some data that I would like to enclose in the headers, but I get the above error regarding namespace.

I can inspect the whole set of headers, and see mine 'SessionID' under the AllKeys section (in VS) but don't understand what namespace it is expecting if any.

In JS I kick off the request like this with no explicit header:

> ```
>       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SessionID", $scope.Psession);
>         xmlhttp.send(body);
> ```

and in C# WCF service this line is where I would like to get the header

```
string session = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("SessionID", "??? WHAT GOES HERE ???");
```

Ultimately, I either need to know what namespace the header is under when I don't declare it myself, or how I can declare it so I know what to search for. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't know the the namesspace, you can loop in headers, look this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407645/4730201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you want to test to see if the header exists before actually getting it, like this:

```
    private bool IsAuthorizedRequest()
    {
        var incomingMessageHeaders = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;

        if (incomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("Authorization", GlobalConstants.WcfNamespace) < 0)
            return false;

        string providedAuthorizationKey = incomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("Authorization", GlobalConstants.WcfNamespace);

        string actualAuthorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthorizationKey");

        return providedAuthorizationKey == actualAuthorizationKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I still have not figured out my original question, but this allows me to get the results I desired. Hope this helps someone.

```
string SessionValue = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("SessionID");
```